# Unexpected token import when run jest test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, tdd, jestjs

Firstly I just want to say that I searched and tried a lot before I asked this question and I saw a lot simillar topics but anyone gives me an answer.

I'm using react, redux, redux-form, webpack, css-modules.

And try to test my project by using jest and I get this error :

> C:\PROJECT\node_modules\redux-form\es\getFormValues.js:1
>
> import createGetFormValues from './selectors/getFormValues';
>
> ^^^^^^ SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

I think that redux-form isn't compiled to es5 before test.

My **test.test.js** looks like :

```
import React from 'react';
import {configure,render} from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-15';

import TestComponent from '../../../components/TestComponent ';

describe('TestComponent ', () => {
    configure({adapter: new Adapter()});

    it('snapshot', () => {
        expect(render(<TestComponent/>)).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
});
```

My **.babaelrc** config file looks like :

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-class-properties",
    "transform-decorators",
    "transform-object-rest-spread"
  ]
}
```

My `package.json` jest configuration looks like :

```
"jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "PROJECT/**/*.{js}"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(css|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    }
  }
```

How I should correctly configure this, jest, to don't have any errors ?

Comment: Does this work if you replace <TestComponent /> within a simple inline Component. For example, add a HelloWorld component into your test.test.js and see if this renders.

Comment: Have you simply tried to import that module in the jest file?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to change imports of my component from :

```
import getFormValuesfrom "redux-form\es\getFormValues";
```

to

```
import { getFormValues} from "redux-form"
```